# Wagtail isssues: ImportError: cannot import name 'filter_page_type' from 'wagtail.admin.views.chooser'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, wagtail

I upgraded to **Wagtail==2.15.2** and **Django==3.0.5**

When I run `python manage.py runserver`

I get the error below

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/me/projects/mysite/slate/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    from slate.editor import urls as admin_editor_urls
  File "/home/me/projects/mysite/slate/editor/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    from slate.editor.views import (
  File "/home/me/projects/mysite/slate/editor/views.py", line 18, in <module>
    from wagtail.admin.views.chooser import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'filter_page_type' from 'wagtail.admin.views.chooser' (/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/chooser.py)
```

The reported file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
slate.editor.views
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

This file contains slate editor's custom views.
@see https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/views/chooser.py  # noqa: E501
"""


from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

from wagtail.admin.forms.search import SearchForm
from wagtail.admin.modal_workflow import render_modal_workflow
from wagtail.admin.views.chooser import (
    can_choose_page,
    filter_page_type,
    page_models_from_string,
    shared_context,
)
from wagtail.core import hooks
from wagtail.core.models import Page, UserPagePermissionsProxy

from slate.editor.forms import (
    AnchorLinkChooserForm,
    EmailLinkChooserForm,
    ExternalLinkChooserForm,
    InternalLinkChooserForm,
    PhoneLinkChooserForm
)


def browse(request, parent_page_id=None):
    # A missing or empty page_type parameter indicates 'all page types'
    # (i.e. descendants of wagtailcore.page)
    page_type_string = request.GET.get('page_type') or 'wagtailcore.page'
    user_perm = request.GET.get('user_perms', False)
    initial_data = {
        'classes': request.GET.get('classes', ''),
    }

    form = InternalLinkChooserForm(initial=initial_data,
                                   prefix='external-link-chooser')

    try:
        desired_classes = page_models_from_string(page_type_string)
    except (ValueError, LookupError):
        raise Http404

    # Find parent page
    if parent_page_id:
        parent_page = get_object_or_404(Page, id=parent_page_id)
    elif desired_classes == (Page,):
        # Just use the root page
        parent_page = Page.get_first_root_node()
    else:
        # Find the highest common ancestor for the specific classes passed in
        # In many cases, such as selecting an EventPage under an EventIndex,
        # this will help the administrator find their page quicker.
        all_desired_pages = filter_page_type(Page.objects.all(),
                                             desired_classes)
        parent_page = all_desired_pages.first_common_ancestor()

    parent_page = parent_page.specific

    # Get children of parent page
    pages = parent_page.get_children().specific()

    # allow hooks to modify the queryset
    for hook in hooks.get_hooks('construct_page_chooser_queryset'):
        pages = hook(pages, request)

    # Filter them by page type
    if desired_classes != (Page,):
        # restrict the page listing to just those pages that:
        # - are of the given content type (taking into account class
        # inheritance)
        # - or can be navigated into (i.e. have children)
        choosable_pages = filter_page_type(pages, desired_classes)
        descendable_pages = pages.filter(numchild__gt=0)
        pages = choosable_pages | descendable_pages

    can_choose_root = request.GET.get('can_choose_root', False)

    # Do permission lookups for this user now, instead of for every page.
    permission_proxy = UserPagePermissionsProxy(request.user)

    # Parent page can be chosen if it is a instance of desired_classes
    parent_page.can_choose = can_choose_page(
        parent_page, permission_proxy, desired_classes, can_choose_root,
        user_perm)

    # Pagination
    # We apply pagination first so we don't need to walk the entire list
    # in the block below
    paginator = Paginator(pages, per_page=25)
    pages = paginator.get_page(request.GET.get('p'))

    # Annotate each page with can_choose/can_decend flags
    for page in pages:
        page.can_choose = can_choose_page(page, permission_proxy,
                                          desired_classes, can_choose_root,
                                          user_perm)
        page.can_descend = page.get_children_count()

    # Render
    context = shared_context(request, {
        'parent_page': parent_page,
        'parent_page_id': parent_page.pk,
        'pages': pages,
        'search_form': SearchForm(),
        'page_type_string': page_type_string,
        'page_type_names': [desired_class.get_verbose_name() for desired_class
                            in desired_classes],
        'page_types_restricted': (page_type_string != 'wagtailcore.page'),
        'form': form,
    })

    return render_modal_workflow(
        request,
        'wagtailadmin/chooser/browse.html', None,
        context,
        json_data={'step': 'browse', 'parent_page_id':
                   context['parent_page_id']},
    )


def search(request, parent_page_id=None):
    # A missing or empty page_type parameter indicates 'all page types' (i.e.
    # descendants of wagtailcore.page)
    page_type_string = request.GET.get('page_type') or 'wagtailcore.page'

    try:
        desired_classes = page_models_from_string(page_type_string)
    except (ValueError, LookupError):
        raise Http404

    pages = Page.objects.all()
    # allow hooks to modify the queryset
    for hook in hooks.get_hooks('construct_page_chooser_queryset'):
        pages = hook(pages, request)

    search_form = SearchForm(request.GET)
    if search_form.is_valid() and search_form.cleaned_data['q']:
        pages = pages.exclude(
            depth=1  # never include root
        )
        pages = filter_page_type(pages, desired_classes)
        pages = pages.specific()
        pages = pages.search(search_form.cleaned_data['q'])
    else:
        pages = pages.none()

    paginator = Paginator(pages, per_page=25)
    pages = paginator.get_page(request.GET.get('p'))

    for page in pages:
        page.can_choose = True

    return render(
        request, 'wagtailadmin/chooser/_search_results.html',
        shared_context(request, {
            'searchform': search_form,
            'pages': pages,
            'page_type_string': page_type_string,
        })
    )


def external_link(request):
    initial_data = {
        'url': request.GET.get('link_url', ''),
        'link_text': request.GET.get('link_text', ''),
        'classes': request.GET.get('classes', ''),
    }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExternalLinkChooserForm(request.POST, initial=initial_data,
                                       prefix='external-link-chooser')

        if form.is_valid():
            result = {
                'url': form.cleaned_data['url'],
                'title': form.cleaned_data['link_text'].strip()
                    or form.cleaned_data['url'],  # noqa: E131
                'classes': form.cleaned_data['classes'],
                # If the user has explicitly entered / edited something in the
                # link_text field, always use that text. If not, we should
                # favour keeping the existing link/selection text, where
                # applicable. (Normally this will match the link_text passed in
                # the URL here anyhow, but that won't account for non-text
                # content such as images.)
                'prefer_this_title_as_link_text': ('link_text' in
                                                   form.changed_data),
            }

            return render_modal_workflow(
                request, None, None,
                None, json_data={'step': 'external_link_chosen',
                                 'result': result}
            )
    else:
        form = ExternalLinkChooserForm(initial=initial_data,
                                       prefix='external-link-chooser')

    return render_modal_workflow(
        request,
        'wagtailadmin/chooser/external_link.html', None,
        shared_context(request, {
            'form': form,
        }), json_data={'step': 'external_link'}
    )


def anchor_link(request):
    initial_data = {
        'link_text': request.GET.get('link_text', ''),
        'url': request.GET.get('link_url', ''),
        'classes': request.GET.get('classes', ''),
    }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AnchorLinkChooserForm(request.POST, initial=initial_data,
                                     prefix='anchor-link-chooser')

        if form.is_valid():
            result = {
                'url': '#' + form.cleaned_data['url'],
                'title': form.cleaned_data['link_text'].strip() or form.cleaned_data['url'],  # noqa: E501
                'prefer_this_title_as_link_text': ('link_text' in
                                                   form.changed_data),
                'classes': form.cleaned_data['classes'],
            }
            return render_modal_workflow(
                request, None, None,
                None, json_data={'step': 'external_link_chosen',
                                 'result': result}
            )
    else:
        form = AnchorLinkChooserForm(initial=initial_data,
                                     prefix='anchor-link-chooser')

    return render_modal_workflow(
        request,
        'wagtailadmin/chooser/anchor_link.html', None,
        shared_context(request, {
            'form': form,
        }), json_data={'step': 'anchor_link'}
    )


def email_link(request):
    initial_data = {
        'link_text': request.GET.get('link_text', ''),
        'email_address': request.GET.get('link_url', ''),
        'classes': request.GET.get('classes', ''),
    }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailLinkChooserForm(request.POST, initial=initial_data,
                                    prefix='email-link-chooser')

        if form.is_valid():
            result = {
                'url': 'mailto:' + form.cleaned_data['email_address'],
                'title': form.cleaned_data['link_text'].strip() or form.cleaned_data['email_address'],  # noqa: E501
                'classes': form.cleaned_data['classes'],
                # If the user has explicitly entered / edited something in the
                # link_text field, always use that text. If not, we should
                # favour keeping the existing link/selection text, where
                # applicable.
                'prefer_this_title_as_link_text': ('link_text' in
                                                   form.changed_data),
            }
            return render_modal_workflow(
                request, None, None,
                None, json_data={'step': 'external_link_chosen',
                                 'result': result}
            )
    else:
        form = EmailLinkChooserForm(initial=initial_data,
                                    prefix='email-link-chooser')

    return render_modal_workflow(
        request,
        'wagtailadmin/chooser/email_link.html', None,
        shared_context(request, {
            'form': form,
        }), json_data={'step': 'email_link'}
    )


def phone_link(request):
    initial_data = {
        'link_text': request.GET.get('link_text', ''),
        'phone_number': request.GET.get('link_url', ''),
        'classes': request.GET.get('classes', ''),
    }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PhoneLinkChooserForm(request.POST, initial=initial_data,
                                    prefix='phone-link-chooser')

        if form.is_valid():
            result = {
                'url': 'tel:' + form.cleaned_data['phone_number'],
                'title': form.cleaned_data['link_text'].strip() or form.cleaned_data['phone_number'],  # noqa: E501
                'classes': form.cleaned_data['classes'],
                # If the user has explicitly entered / edited something in the
                # link_text field, always use that text. If not, we should
                # favour keeping the existing link/selection text, where
                # applicable.
                'prefer_this_title_as_link_text': ('link_text' in
                                                   form.changed_data),
            }
            return render_modal_workflow(
                request, None, None,
                None, json_data={'step': 'external_link_chosen',
                                 'result': result}
            )
    else:
        form = PhoneLinkChooserForm(initial=initial_data,
                                    prefix='phone-link-chooser')

    return render_modal_workflow(
        request,
        'wagtailadmin/chooser/phone_link.html', None,
        shared_context(request, {
            'form': form,
        }), json_data={'step': 'phone_link'}
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

`filter_page_type` was an undocumented internal function for Wagtail's own use, and was [removed in Wagtail 2.13](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/commit/26561b2ea500b0f462efe0559403af0342c07992). You can achieve the same thing with the [`type` method on PageQuerySet](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/queryset_reference.html#wagtail.core.query.PageQuerySet.type):

```
pages = filter_page_type(pages, desired_classes)
```

would become

```
pages = pages.type(*desired_classes)
```

However, since this code looks like it's been copied wholesale from an earlier version of Wagtail, it's quite possible that it'll depend on other internal details that have changed in the latest Wagtail release. If this is the case, it may be best to recreate your custom code based on the current Wagtail codebase, or rewrite it to avoid relying on undocumented Wagtail internals.

Comment: Please add more details on how I can use this. I have updated my question with more details for this slate/editor/views.py

Comment: OK, updated now.